# How to use ES6 features like generators in netbeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, generator

```
Promise.coroutine(function* () {

  var profile = yield $.get('profile.json');
  $status.append('<li>got profile</li>');
  $('#profile-pre').html(JSON.stringify(profile));

  var tweets = yield $.get('tweets.json?id='+profile.id);
  $status.append('<li>got tweets</li>');
  $('#tweets-pre').html(JSON.stringify(tweets));

  var friend = yield $.get('friend.json?id='+tweets[0].usersMentioned[0].id);
  $status.append('<li>got friend</li>');
  $('#friend-pre').html(JSON.stringify(friend));

})().catch(function(errs) {
  handle errors on any events
})
```

When I try to execute this code in netbeans,it doesn't allow to use generators?How to rectify this?

Comment: I believe `Promise.coroutine` is not a standard method of ES6 promise object. You should probably try writing your own spawn function. Or you might try importing bluebird.

Comment: @Redu Could you please tell me how to import 'BlueBird'.I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: For the browser you should add `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.4.1/bluebird.min.js"></script>` inside the `<head>`. You can find more options in Bluebird's web page like Node installation: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/install.html#node-installation. I am not fond of any libraries if the functionality already exists in the language. Couroutines are not that difficult to implement in standard ES6.  I would recommend you to study the promises and generators of ES6 to implement them yourself. Check https://curiosity-driven.org/promises-and-generators as well.